# How to take screenshot of KDE task switcher?

Tags: kde, kubuntu, screenshot, window-switching

I've tried hotkeys using Spectacle, but even when I use the hotkeys when the screen shots what I want, it doesn't work - I guess because I can only use those hotkeys by tricking the app switcher into not disappearing by carefully shifting from <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> to <kbd>Win+PrintScreen</kbd>

Is there some way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open any terminal application.
2. Install scrot (`sudo apt install scrot`)
3. Type:

```
sleep 5; scrot myimage.png
```

Minimize the terminal window, do what you want. Find `myimage.png` in your $HOME.

Comment: Works beautifully! Thank you very much!